# Problems with AsyncStorage in React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, authentication, asyncstorage

I am building my first React Native app. I am in the process of making the automatic login with AsyncStorage. I already got the login page figured out and I managed to store the user in AsyncStorage. But in the

App.js

```
import { createAppContainer } from 'react-navigation';
import { createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigation-stack';
import Login from './components/login'
import Signup from './components/signup'
import Home from './components/home'
import Profile from './components/profile';


const getData = async (user) => {
  try {
      const value = await AsyncStorage.getItem('@userauthkey')
      if (value !== null) {
          return value
      } else {
          return false
      }
  } catch (e) {
      console.log(e)
  }
}
const c = async () => {

const ch =  await getData('@userauthkey')
return ch
}


console.log(c())


const AppNavigator = createStackNavigator({
  Login: {screen: Login},
  Signup: {screen: Signup},
  Home: {screen: Home},
  Profile: {screen: Profile},
  
})

  const AppNavigator2 = createStackNavigator({
    Home: {screen: Home},
    Login: {screen: Login},
    Signup: {screen: Signup},
    Home: {screen: Home},
    Profile: {screen: Profile},
    
  })




const App = createAppContainer(c() == false ? AppNavigator : AppNavigator2)




export default App;
```

I get "Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {_U, _V, _W, _X}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead." How can I fix it to make it sign the user in automatically?
login screen

```
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar'
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import { TextInput } from 'react-native-gesture-handler';
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, FlatList, Image, Button, Pressable, ScrollView } from 'react-native';


export default function Login(props) {

    const message = props.navigation.getParam('message', null)
    const [username, setUsername] = useState("")
    const [password, setPassword] = useState("")

    const setStringValue = async (value, user) => {
        try {

            await AsyncStorage.setItem(user, value)
        } catch (e) {
            console.log(e)
        }
    }

    const getData = async (user) => {
        try {
            const value = await AsyncStorage.getItem('@userauthkey')
            if (value !== null) {
                return value
            } else {
                return false
            }
        } catch (e) {
            console.log(e)
        }
    }

    const log = () => {

        fetch(`http://192.168.5.223:8000/home/login/`, {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                "Content-Type": 'application/json'
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({ username: username, password: password }),
        })
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(async (res) => {
                console.log(res)

                if (res.valid === true) {

                    await setStringValue(username, '@userauthkey')

                    let ch = await getData(username)

                    console.log(ch)

                    if (res.set === true) {
                        props.navigation.navigate("Home", { "user": username })
                    } else {
                        props.navigation.navigate("Profile", { "user": username })
                    }

                } else {
                    props.navigation.navigate("Login", { 'message': "username/password are incorrect" })
                }

            })
            .catch(error => console.log(error))

    }

    const sign = () => {

        props.navigation.navigate("Signup")

    }

    return (
        <View style={styles.container} >
            <ScrollView style={styles.scroll} >
                <View style={styles.main}>
                    <Text style={styles.error}> {message} </Text>
                    < Text style={styles.label} >
                        Username:
                    </Text>
                    <TextInput style={styles.input} placeholder="Username"
                        onChangeText={text => setUsername(text)} value={username}
                        autoCapitalize={'none'}
                    />

                    <Text style={styles.label}> Password: </Text>
                    <TextInput style={styles.input} placeholder="Password" onChangeText={text => setPassword(text)}
                        value={password} secureTextEntry={true} autoCapitalize={'none'}
                    />


                    <Button onPress={() => log()} title="Login" > </Button>
                </View>
            </ScrollView>
            < View style={styles.footer} >
                <Button onPress={() => sign()} title="Don't have an acount? Sign up now" />
            </View>
            < StatusBar style="auto" />
        </View>
    )
}

Login.navigationOptions = screenProps => ({
    headerLeft: () => null,
    gestureEnabled: false,
    headerStyle: {
        backgroundColor: 'black'
    },
    headerTintColor: 'white',

})
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  error: {
    textAlign: 'center',
    color: 'red',
  },

  main: {
    paddingTop: 145,
    paddingHorizontal: 5,
  },

  container: {
    flex: 1, 
    backgroundColor: 'black',
    
  },
  
  scroll: {
    backgroundColor:'#'
  },

  footer: {
    borderTopColor: '#fff',
    padding:35,
  },

  label: {
    fontSize: 24,
    color: "white",
    padding: 10,

  },

  input: {
    fontSize: 24,
    backgroundColor: "white",
    padding: 10,
    margin: 10,
    borderRadius: 5,
  },


  
});
```

Comment: Which version of `react-navigation` are you using?

Comment: I am using version 4.4.4

Comment: Can you show me the `Login` and the `Home` screen implementation?

Comment: I added the login screen

Comment: I am now getting the same thing for the Login screen

Comment: The Login screen worked before

Answer (score 0):

Did you imported AsyncStorage in your app.js?

```
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';
```

You used it but didn't import it, in the code shown. Try to import it and recompile